# How to set word spacing in SWT font

Tags: java, swt

I'm using SWT and want to use `gc's` `drawstring` function, but I can't set the word spacing of the font, is there any way to do so? Thanks

**Update**
I've tried `TexetLayout` with the code

```
TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(printer);
layout.setWidth(gc.stringExtent(text).x / 2);
layout.setText(text);
layout.draw(gc, x, y);
```

FYI, i"m trying to use the printer and `gc` is constructed  with `printer` too, but I didn't get anything printed on the paper, am I wrong about the use of `textlayout`, or could you pls provide some code snippet for me to  reference?

Comment: Add code you  tried with.

Comment: sorry for the misguide, I don't know how to set the word spacing, so My question should be **how to set the word spacing?** I've did some search and didn't find a way to get it work. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround that may not be perfect, I used `Transform's scale` to set the width to a certain value and in this way. the word spacing didn't change but the total width of a word is changed which can kind of satisfy me.

Answer (score 1):

`GC` `drawString` and `drawText` don't have any support for this.

You can use `GC.textExtent` to get the length of text which you could use lay out the text yourself.

The `TextLayout` class has some support for text justification.

Update: There are a number of examples of using TextLayout [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/0860__TextLayout.htm)

Comment: I've viewed the page but still didn't find out how to set the word spacing.. which method can deal with it ?

Comment: I did not say it could do word spacing. I said it supported justification - `setJustify(true)`.